# groupby with multiple columns with addition and frequency counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, multiple-columns

I have a table that is looks like follows:

```
name  type    val 
A     online  12
B     online  24
A     offline 45
B     online  32
A     offline 43
B     offline 44
```

I want to `dataframe` in such a manner that it can be `groupby` with multiple cols `name` & `type`, which also have additional columns that return the `count` of the record with `val` being added of the same type records. It should be like follows:

```
name    type    count   val
A       online  1       12
        offline 2       88
B       online  2       56
        offline 1       44
```

I have tried `pd.groupby(['name', 'type'])['val'].sum()` that gives the addition but unable to add the count of records.

Answer (score 2):

Add parameter `sort=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for avoid default sorting and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with tuples with new columns names and aggregate functions, last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `MultiIndex` to columns:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['name', 'type'], sort=False)['val']
        .agg([('count', 'count'),('val', 'sum')])
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
  name     type  count  val
0    A   online      1   12
1    B   online      2   56
2    A  offline      2   88
3    B  offline      1   44
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try pivoting i.e

```
df.pivot_table(index=['name','type'],aggfunc=['count','sum'],values='val')

             count sum
               val val
name type             
A    offline     2  88
     online      1  12
B    offline     1  44
     online      2  56
```

Comment: what if there are many cols rather than these 3 columns? Do I have to somehow mention particular columnname for aggfunc?

Comment: Yeah its simple. There's a values parameter in pivot table. You can simply add `values='val'`